# Minimize Performance Issues of MultiSite Large Number of Tables Created

Tags: multisite, sql, performance

I am deploying WordPress MultiSite and if I get a decent amount of users, I will have thousands of database tables to support all of these sites. I like the idea of consolidating all of these tables to a single set of tables to make multisite more manageable and also more optimized for SQL Server. Has anyone had experience with a large number of tables issue in multisite?

**Edit:** Basically I want to understand the performance impact of having thousands of tables added over time?

Comment: It's completely impossible to understand your question. Please take a step back, rethink your problem and file an [edit] to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, WordPress.com it's the largest deployment of WordPress Multisite and they're basically using the same setup (multiple tables for each site), so you could say that it's a good strategy.

This kind of setup would let you to, for instance, keep your VIP users on a dedicated box, or add multiple DB servers as the network grows.

I've had experience with networks of about 500 sites and some basic tuning it's enough to keep the sites working.

Also, check the [HyperDB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/) plugin, which it's a replacement for WordPress' default DB class that "supports replication, failover, load balancing, and partitioning"